# Ограничить количество логов FIFO

Tags: mysql, yii2, логирование

У меня логи пишутся в базу (`yii\log\DbTarget`), это удобно, но со временем накапливаются тысячи старых логов которые вообщем-то уже не нужны и только замедляют открытие этой таблицы когда надо посмотреть что-то. Хотелось бы чтобы они либо по дате либо по количеству начинали удаляться (самые старые) при достижении какого-то лимита. Например чтобы единовременно только за неделю хранились. Не нашел у логгера Yii такого функционала... Может это на mysql как-то сделать? (триггер там или еще что-то) Или как вариант по крону просто запускать скрипт который будет подчищать устаревшие логи.

Comment: Ну так кроном же можно удалять.

Comment: @fedornabilkin ну да, как вариант. Я об этом и говорю... Просто думал может есть более изящное решение. Или во фреймворке что-то для этого все-таки предусмотрено или какой-то дополнительной библиотекой...

Comment: Или чистить таблицу от старых записей по эвенту (встроенный шедулер MySQL), или вместо записи организовать ротацию (не вставлять новую запись, а обновлять самую старую). *Или во фреймворке* У тебя проблема на уровне MySQL - вот нахрена тебе для решения этой проблемы ещё один уровень?